# Implement FirestoreQuery with LiveData updates : Android Firestore RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

How to implement Firestore Query with LiveData by getting real-time updates or changes?

Earlier I worked with a single document snapshot and that works fine for me but now I want to deal with the list of documents or query.

Implementation for Single Document as shown below (Working) :

```
class ItemLiveData(private val reference: DocumentReference) :
LiveData<Item> () , EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> {

private var registration : ListenerRegistration? = null

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    registration = reference.addSnapshotListener(this)
}

override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    registration?.remove()
}

override fun onEvent(value: DocumentSnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
    value?.let {
        setValue(Item(it.id,it.getString("name")!!))
    }
} }
```

ViewModel Implementation :

```
 private val firestore = Firebase.firestore.collection("cities")

fun getItemLiveData(): ItemLiveData {
    return ItemLiveData(firestore.document("IGjSiK0mDVQp20zWqNMD"))
}
```

Alright code given above working perfectly for a single document but what if with queries?

I am trying to implement something like this :

```
class FirestoreQueryLiveData(private val query: Query)
: LiveData<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(), EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {

private lateinit var registration: ListenerRegistration

override fun onActive() {
    super.onActive()
    registration = query.addSnapshotListener(this)
}

override fun onInactive() {
    super.onInactive()
    registration.remove()
}

override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
    val documents:List<DocumentSnapshot> = value?.documents as List<DocumentSnapshot>
    postValue(documents)
}
```

}

Help me if I have done any mistakes anywhere in the code?

**My question is**: How to cast these QuerySnapshot into a List and update the existing list or RecyclerView?

Comment: Have you tried to convert the `List<DocumentSnapshot>` into `List<Item>` and pass it to your adapter?

Comment: How to do that because it's a list and its returning List<DocumentSnapshot> in the observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, make your `FirestoreQueryLiveData` class extend LiveData<List> and change the content of your `onEvent()` method like below:

```
class FirestoreQueryLiveData(
    private val query: Query
): LiveData<List<Item>>(), EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
    private lateinit var registration: ListenerRegistration

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        registration = query.addSnapshotListener(this)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        registration.remove()
    }

    override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
        val items = ArrayList<Item>()
        for (doc in value!!) {
            doc.toObject(Item::class.java).let {
                items.add(it)
            }
        }
        postValue(items)
    }
}
```

Now you have added to your LiveData object a List of type Item, and now can be used in your adapter to display the data in the UI.

Comment: I wrote an article called [How to paginate Firestore using Paging 3 on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df). It's without real-time updates. However, I'm sure that are ways to do that, but not tried yet.

Comment: You should add Kotlin Coroutine dependencies in order to make it work.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to say what's wrong. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: please help me at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819231/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values-android