# Firestore search array contains for multiple values Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-ktx

I am using Cloud Firestore and within collections,one named "channels" containing the following values ->
[image]

```
users : ["_id1","_id2"]
```

I have to search in a way to check both the values from users array.
I am trying this way but its giving me nothing

```
db.collections("channels").WhereArrayContains("users", listOf("_id1","_id2")).get()
```

But the search is not getting the results. Because it seems the query is incorrect. What is the solution for it? please mention the query for it.

Note - WhereField is deprecated in android so I can't use it anymore.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I mentioned firestore that clearly means Cloud Firestore not realtime database

Comment: @nirazv You tagged with both, which I fixed for you. Having only relevant tags on a question increases the chance that someone will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try `db.collection("channels").WhereArrayContains("users", listOf("_id1","_id2")).get()` - you referenced the db collection in plural and missed the closing quote in the collection name which might be the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: its my mistek at the time of posting this question, by the way if i was missed quote then it would give me a compilation error, but its not, the query itself is not valid

Comment: @nirazv what about `db.collections` > `db.collection`?